# Writing to new text file after splitting delimiters in python

Tags: python

Am generating a text file using python script like below

```
(1,2,3)(4,5,6)
```

If I need to split this to 2 lines with delimiter, how can i do that. 
I need the text file to be like

```
  (1,2,3)
  (4,5,6)
```

Thanks

Comment: Got anything you tried before deciding you needed to seek help? We're really here to share knowledge and show you what you're missing, not just provide a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
a="(1,2,3)(4,5,6)"
a=a.split(")(")
with open("file.txt",'w') as file:
    file.write(a[0]+")"+"\n"+"("+a[1])
```

Try this and then save to a file with newlines.

Comment: tried this it worked,but if I hv some 100of lines, hw to iterate.also am hvng the strings in a text file so first have to read the strings from text file

Comment: Put the code in a function with argument `a`, run the function on each of the 100 lines (which you can put in a list).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a loop to do this, below is my experiment, and then you can store this result to a text file:

```
str = "(1,2,3)(4,5,6)"

def transform_str(data):
    lines = []
    start_pos = 0
    end_pos = 0
    while end_pos < len(data) - 1:
        start_pos = data[end_pos:].find('(') + end_pos
        end_pos = data[start_pos:].find(')') + start_pos
        lines.append(data[start_pos : end_pos+1])
    return lines

lines = transform_str(str)
for line in lines:
    print(line)

(1,2,3)
(4,5,6)
```